# How do I install Ubuntu on a Sony Vaio SVT1311?

Tags: installation, dual-boot, vaio, sony

I am wondering if I could get assistance of how to install Ubuntu on my Sony Vaio T.
SVT131A11L is the hardware configuration code and the model number of the computer is one among the SVT1311 series.

I contacted Sony customer service but their answer was to contact a Linux representative.

The bugging error with Vaio devices is they are build to run windows and it doesnt come configured with a dual boot option, I am wondering if I could get any assistance of how to solve it, or where I could get related information.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 12.04 apresenta opção de instalação simultânea com outros sistemas instalados, no inicio da instalação quando pergunta se apaga tudo do disco e instala o Ubuntu responda "NÃO" APOS ISSO APRESENTA OUTRAS OPÇÕES: disco externo é uma, no próprio disco windows dividindo o espaço e formatando a partição linux para seu uso, pode instalar outro disco interno ao notebook.

Eu preciso as especificações técnicas de fábrica do modelo Notebook "Vaio svt131a11l" se puder me enviar agradeço.

Saúl

Translated using google translate

Ubuntu 12.04 installation option provides simultaneous with other systems installed at the beginning of the installation when asked if erases all the disk and install Ubuntu answer "NO" OTHER OPTIONS AFTER THAT PRESENTS: external disk is in the disk itself windows dividing the space and formatting the partition to use Linux, you can install another internal drive to the notebook.

I need the technical specifications of the factory model notebook "Vaio svt131a11l" if you can send me thank.

Saul